# useState updates but changes doesnt show

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect, use-state

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import PostCard from './PostCard'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    CardContainer: {
      display: "block"
    },
  }));

export default function CardContainer() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(()=>{
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => setPosts(res))
      },[])

    console.log(posts)

return (<div className={classes.CardContainer} >
      {!posts.length ? <h1>Loading</h1> : 
      posts.map((post) => {
        <PostCard postInfo={post}/>
      })}
  </div>
  );
}
```

with this code i see no PostCard component.
In the console first writes an empty array then the response from fetch
so it fetches correctly but doesnt re-return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your `.map` function:

```js
posts.map((post) => {
  <PostCard postInfo={post}/>
})}
```

Either use an explicit `return`:

```js
posts.map((post) => {
  return <PostCard postInfo={post}/>;
})}
```

Or remove the function body:

```js
posts.map((post) =>
  <PostCard postInfo={post}/>
)}
```